# How to convert an object to a string with a format string?

Tags: c#

I have an `object` which may be boxed from `int`, `float`, `decimal`, `DateTime`, `TimeSpan` etc.
Now I want to convert it to a `string` with a format string, such as `"D4"`, `"P2"`, or `"yyyyMMdd"`. But the `object` class doesn't have a `ToString` method which receives the format string. So the following code doesn't work.

```
string Format(object value, string format)
{
    return value.ToString(format); // error
}
```

Below is my ugly workaround.

```
string Format(object value, string format)
{
    if (value is int) return ((int)value).ToString(format);
    if (value is float) return ((float)value).ToString(format);
    if (value is double) return ((double)value).ToString(format);
    if (value is decimal) return ((decimal)value).ToString(format);
    if (value is DateTime) return ((DateTime)value).ToString(format);
    if (value is TimeSpan) return ((TimeSpan)value).ToString(format);
    ...
}
```

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense - all of those types have different applicable format strings but your `Format` method gives the impression that any format string can be arbitrarily applied to any object (which is obviously not the case). Seems to me you need to unbox the object first and then decide what format string to use...?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an interface for that, it is [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.iformattable.aspx):

```
public static string Format(object value, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;

    if (formattable != null)
    {
        return formattable.ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("value");
}
```

(this interface is the one used by the various `string.Format`, `Console.Write`, ...)

Comment: @Dai The question was _I have an `object`_, so I can't do what you suggested.

Comment: Theere is an example of use?
IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;  <--- that line makes formattable null so throw new ArgumentException("value") is triggered

Comment: @AndresChica Your object must implement the `IFormattable` interface. If you can't cast it to `IFormattable` it means that it doesn't implement it.